# The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given expressions are list of string and number, respectively

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to create the transit gateway VPC attachment using the terraform code however, I am getting below error when I execute the terraform plan;
terraform version is 0.12

error:-

```
│ Error: Inconsistent conditional result types
│
│   on vpn-dynamic\main.tf line 67, in resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment" "tgw_vpc_attachment":
│   67:   subnet_ids         = lower(var.transit_gateway) == "enabled" ? var.tgw_subnet_ids : 0
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.tgw_subnet_ids is a list of string, known only after apply
│     │ var.transit_gateway is a string, known only after apply
│
│ The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given expressions are list of      
│ string and number, respectively.
```

main.tf:-

```
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment" "tgw_vpc_attachment" {
  count              = lower(var.transit_gateway) == "enabled" ? 1 : 0
  subnet_ids         = lower(var.transit_gateway) == "enabled" ? var.tgw_subnet_ids : 0
  transit_gateway_id = lower(var.transit_gateway) == "enabled" ? var.tgw_id : 0
  vpc_id             = lower(var.transit_gateway) == "enabled" ? var.vpc_id : 0
}
```

variable.tf:-

```
variable "transit_gateway" {
  type        = string
  description = "Whether to create Transit gateway or not"
  default     = "ENABLED"
}
variable "tgw_subnet_ids" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "Transit gateway subnet Ids"
  default     = ["subnet-12345", "subnet-54321"]
}
variable "vpc_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "VPC Id"
  default     = "vpc-abc123"
}
variable "tgw_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "TGW id"
  default     = "tgw-12345"
}
```

Here I am trying to use variable "tgw_subnet_ids" as a list(string) with the condition in resource "tgw_vpc_attachment" but it's not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe, what terraform is looking for is consistent types on both side of True and False evaluation.

So in your code , the true evaluation returns list type `var.tgw_subnet_ids` and false evaluation returns just integer `0`. As you can see both are not matching and terraform is erroring out.

If you want to pass the null value of the list , you can just use `null` type https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/types.html#null

```
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment" "tgw_vpc_attachment" {
  count              = lower(var.transit_gateway) == "enabled" ? 1 : 0
  subnet_ids         = lower(var.transit_gateway) == "enabled" ? var.tgw_subnet_ids : null
  transit_gateway_id = lower(var.transit_gateway) == "enabled" ? var.tgw_id : 0
  vpc_id             = lower(var.transit_gateway) == "enabled" ? var.vpc_id : 0
}
```

Comment: This helped me in organizing the transit gateway outputs.

Comment: I really like this approach and here is why.  Granted, it's unrelated but I'm creating a VM and I want the option to pass a gallery image OR a marketplace image.  I could add something like:

source_image_id = var.passed_image_id != "none" ? var.passed_image_id : null

The issue I've faced is how to create multi like arguments.  thoughts on the Example below:

source_image_id = var.passed_image_id == "none" ? <need multi lined response here> : null

Answer (score 3):

First, not a direct answer to the initial issue, but you do not even need to compare this in every argument

```
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment" "tgw_vpc_attachment" {
  count = lower(var.transit_gateway) == "enabled" ? 1 : 0

  subnet_ids         = var.tgw_subnet_ids
  transit_gateway_id = var.tgw_id
  vpc_id             = var.vpc_id
}
```

the resource will only be created if the first condition is true... so checking it again inside is redundant.

The error you see is based on the fact that terraform has a very strict way of handling types. When conditionally setting argument values it is always best to have `null` in the `else` case of the condition so the providers go with ther internal defaults or ignore the argument completely.